# How Auth works with SocketIO?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-sockets

I'm new to web sockets (specifically to socketIO interfaces, both client and server), and I wonder how basic JWT auth is usually implemented. How the headers are passed through. Should I add them to every socket listener or emit event? Or just once during the connection. Maybe the connection is already considered private because of the connection id?

I am using Socket.io-client v.4 and flask-socketio.
I am interested in general practices and would be grateful for any information or your own experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to pass authentication when you connect:

- HTTP header
- Cookie
- query string
- `auth` option

To pass a token in a header (not valid when connecting directly via WebSocket):

```js
const socket = io({
  extraHeaders: {
    "Header-Name": "abcd"
  }
});
```

Same site cookies are always passed to the server. To pass cookies cross-site:

```js
const socket = io("https://my-backend.com", {
  withCredentials: true
});
```

To pass it in the query string:

```js
const socket = io({
  query: {
    token: 'abcd'
  }
});
```

To pass it with the `auth` option (Socket.IO v3 and up only):

```js
const socket = io({
  auth: {
    token: "abcd"
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's extremely informative)